# How to give External Users Access to Certain SubSites?

Tags: permissions, user-accounts

I am looking to invite a few accounts from outside my org. But I have 12 SubSites and I want to give them access to only 4 of them.

How do I do this?

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Are the subsites inheriting permissions? If yes, you need to break the inheritance on these 4 subsites and add the external users amongst the other user permissions. If they already have non-inheriting permissions, you can directly add the users to the subsites' permission group of desired permission level.

Comment: My SubSites are inheriting the permissions, Where would i go to disable this?

Comment: Comment field couldn't fit my answer properly, so answered in full-length below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subsites which should be allowed for the external users need to have unique permissions, meaning their permissions must not inherit from the parent site. To break the permission inheritance, navigate to **Site Settings** > **Site permissions** and from the toolbar select **Stop Inheriting Permissions**.

After this, you must select the permission groups you wish to add to the subsite. Likely this will be the groups you had there before (the same as in the parent site), and in addition the external users. If the external users should have a permission level not yet present in the assigned permission groups, you should create a new permission group of desired permission level, and assign the external users to the group.

If you wish to learn more about permission levels, permission groups, permission inheritance and other related information, you should refer to [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848).